# Page Not Loading PartialView HTML

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a C# MVC Razor site that I am attempting to add some HTML to once the user presses a button. The workflow is as follows: the page loads, the user does some stuff (not related to this action), then at some point they click a button which in turn sends an Ajax call to the server to gather some information. That information is loaded into the ViewBag and then a PartialView is returned.

Below is the code for this. The RowPartial.cshtml is indeed being hit and the ViewBag.Rows item does have greater than 0 records in it but the TEST header is not showing up at all. I cannot find it anywhere through the Dev Tools in Chrome. It's hitting the code but not actually adding the HTML to the page. What am I doing wrong?

**Controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetRows()
    {
        ViewBag.Rows = Helpers.GetRows();

        return PartialView("RowPartial");
    }
```

**RowPartial.cshtml**

```
@if (ViewBag.Rows.Count > 0)
{
   <h3>TEST</h3>
}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 25px;">
    @Html.Partial("CourseRowPartial")
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the html response where you are calling the GetRows function.
With vanila js you could use something like this:

```
document.getElementById("divRows").innerHTML = ajaxResponse;
```

And instead to have this in index.cshtml

```
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 25px;">
    @Html.Partial("CourseRowPartial")
</div>
```

You should have, for example, this

```
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 25px;" id="divRows"></div>
```